# RDBMS to Elastic Search

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Suppose I have 5 tables called `groups`, `posts`, `groups_posts`, `post_comments` and `posts_votes`.

`groups` table has the fields: `user_id`, `name` and `description`, `posts` has the fields: `user_id` and `comment`

Relationship between `groups` and `posts` is MANY_2_MANY so each post can belong to many groups and each group can contain 0-* posts. This is what table `groups_posts` does.

`post_comments` table has the fields: `text`, `post_id`, `user_id`, `added_at`(date), `total_comments`, `total_votes`

`posts_votes` table has the fields: `post_id`, `user_id` and `vote_at`(date)

I want to model these structure in Elastic Search. The main reason I need to have quick search for most popular posts from user groups(user can belong to 0-* group) for a specific user for last 12 hours based on sum of post comments and post votes for this amount of time.

Could you please tell me how to effectively map this on Elastic Search indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to make some decisions.

First, you could create one index for each day so that you only search one index when running queries for the current day.

Since we don't have joins in elasticsearch, you will need to aggregate your data related data together, e.g. Put all data related to a user together, so that your data would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "user_id":123,
    "groups": [
       {
         "name":"my group",
         "posts_by_user":[ // only comments by this user
           {
             "content": "foo bar baz",
             "votes":5
           },
           {
             "content": "bar baz quux",
             "votes": 43
           },
           ... other posts by this user in this group
         ]
       },
       ... other groups 
    ]
  },
  ... other users
```

**Also**: Read this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/modeling-your-data.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one additional question - if I'm not interested in the indexing data by each day but I need to find the posts within a data range - Now(date/time when a search occurs)-12h ? How to organize index in this case ?

Comment: And one more thing - I'm searching not for the user posts(posted by this user), but for the posts that were posted into the groups that this user follows(associated via  groups_posts table with MANY_2_MANY relationship)